# Return statement in function

Tags: javascript, function, promise, sequelize.js

In the below example which i got from Sequelize docs on transactions, I don't understand why you have to add return statements for the queries and also on the sequelize transaction method.

```
 function doTransaction () {
        return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

          // chain all your queries here. make sure you return them.
          return User.create({
            firstName: 'Abraham',
            lastName: 'Lincoln'
          }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {
            return user.setShooter({
              firstName: 'John',
              lastName: 'Boothe'
            }, {transaction: t});
          });

        }).then(function (result) {
          // Transaction has been committed
          // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
        }).catch(function (err) {
          // Transaction has been rolled back
          // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have something in your promise `then` chain that doesn't return anything then it's presumed that method didn't do anything that's part of the chain. It's your responsibility to return a promise if you want to extend the chain. This is one of the basic principles of promise-driven design.

Here the transaction code needs to know when it can commit the transaction. If you don't return promises inside of that block it's going to go ahead and close it long before those insert operations are anywhere close to completed. This is the nature of asynchronous code. You need to coordinate between levels.

If you ever forget to return values in situations like this your code *might* work, but it will also behave unpredictably, introducing subtle errors that can cause chaos if left uncorrected. It's a good idea to develop an eye for what a proper promise looks like now, that `return` statement should be present for anything in the chain, and structure your code so that mistakes are obvious.

Comment: hmm I am not sure I understand what you are saying, I am going to remove the second example i posted because it seems unrelated to the first

Comment: Failing to `return` a promise means the promise chain is free to move on without waiting. If you *do* return something then it's obligated to wait.